# How do I cite something that cites several other papers at once?

Tags: citations, psychology

I’m currently writing an assignment, for which every single piece I would like to cite comes across as such:

> ACEs are associated with a variety of physical and mental health
> problems, including increased risk for problematic drinking and
> development of alcohol and other substance use disorders (Afifi et al.
> 2011; Feliti et al., 1998; Fuller-Thomson, Roane & Brennenstuhl, 2016;
> Meyers et al., 2018).

How would I reference this? Can I reference solely the article it’s from? Because looking into the other papers they also reference several others and none say exactly this either.

Answer (score 1):

First, only cite papers that you have actually read. Don't just passively copy citations from the one paper you read. Second, learn APA in-text citation style. Put a comma after et al. and (new in APA 7th edition) use et al. for three authors even with the first citation.